# Spring Integration WebFlux outboundGateway ClientHttpResponse to Mono<Object>

Tags: spring-integration

How do we convert the `Flux<DataBuffer>` of `ClientHttpResponse` to `Mono<SomeDto>`. Also, can we get access to `MessageHeaders` in the `bodyExtractor`. Please suggest.

```
.handle(WebFlux.outboundGateway(apiUrl, webClient)
                .httpMethod(POST)
                .mappedRequestHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE)
                .bodyExtractor((clientHttpResponse, context) -> validateAPIResponse(clientHttpResponse)))


private Mono<Object> validateAPIResponse(final ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse) {

    var httpStatus = clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode();

    // check for 500
    if (httpStatus.is5xxServerError())
        throw new SomeException(.......);

    var responseMono = new Jackson2JsonDecoder().decodeToMono(clientHttpResponse.getBody(), ResolvableType.forClass(SomDto.class), null,
            null);

    // check for any other than 200
    if (!httpStatus.is2xxSuccessful())
        return responseMono.map(response -> {
            throw new SomeOtherException(response.getSomeField(), httpStatus);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just delegate to `BodyExtractors.toFlux(SomDto.class)`. I'm not sure if you really need a custom `BodyExtractor`, if just `expectedResponseType(SomDto.class)` should be enough for you produce such a `Mono`. Not sure also if you need to handle those errors yourself: the framework does a decent job on the matter.

Yes, you cannot get access to `MessageHeaders` in this `BodyExtractor` context since it has nothing to do with messaging.

You can get access to those headers a bit downstream when you already got a reply from this WebFlux gateway. If your reply is really very tied to headers, then you need to look into producing a generic reply (like that `Flux<DataBuffer>`) and then convert it appropriately downstream in a transformer where you already get access to the whole request message and its headers.

See also this in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/webflux.html#webflux-outbound):

> Spring Integration provides `ClientHttpResponseBodyExtractor` as a identity function to produce (downstream) the whole `ClientHttpResponse` and any other possible custom logic.

Comment: Thx for the detailed explanation. Our use-case is to know the `HttpStatusCode` and act accordingly (infact continue the flow), rather than throwing the message to `errorChannel`. With the normal `expectedResponseType()`, any other than 2xx series were going to the `errorChannel`, hence the need for custom `BodyExtractor`

Comment: Can you please suggest if the framework allows handling `WebFlux` response by `statusCode` rather than going via `errorChannel`?

Comment: No, it does not. You are right: the sensible default behavior is to proceed with `2xx` and fail with `5xx` or `4xx`. So, see if my other suggestion with that `ClientHttpResponseBodyExtractor` can help you.

Comment: Tried custom `BodyExtractor` as well as `ClientHttpResponseBodyExtractor`, in both the cases at the end if it is a non `2xx` status, it is going to the `errorChannel`. Sample available at https://github.com/syedyusufh/webflux-inboundgateway-error, you need a mock endpoint to return 400. Please help

Comment: Hello @Artem, can you please try the sample shared and provide us some suggestions to continue the flow without throwing the `WebFlux` response to `errorChannel`

Comment: The `WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler` currently does this hard code: `.onStatus(HttpStatusCode::isError, ClientResponse::createException)`. See its JavaDocs: I wonder if `ExchangeFilterFunction` injected into the `WebClient` provided for this `WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler` will do the trick to mitigate this concern. For example you can transform `ClientResponse` to not have a bad status code. See `DefaultClientResponseBuilder`.

Comment: Thx a lot, mutating `ClientResponse` via `ExchangeFilterFunction` did the trick, together with a custom header to know the original `HttpStatus`